# What is the output of a piped file stream?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

Perhaps the question is not worded in the greatest way but here's some more context. Using GridFSBucket, I'm able to store a file in mongo and obtain a download stream for that file. Here's my question. Let's say I wanted to send that file back as a response to my http request.

I do:

```
downloadStream.pipe(res);
```

On the client side now when I print the responseText, I get some long string with some funky characters that look to be encrypted. What is the format/type of this string/stream?  How do I setup my response so that I can get the streamed data as an ArrayBuffer on my client side?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I haven't solved the problem yet, however the suggestion by @Jekrb, gives exactly the same output as doing `console.log(this.responseText)`. It looks like the string is not a buffer. Here is the output from these 2 lines:

`console.log(this.responseText.toString('utf8'))`

`var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);`

[image]

UPDATE 2 - THE CODE SNIPPETS

Frontend:

```
    var savePDF = function(blob){
      //fs.writeFile("test.pdf",blob);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200){

            //TO DO: Handle the file in the response which we will be displayed.
            console.log(this.responseText.toString('utf8'));
            var arrayBuffer = this.responseText;
            if (arrayBuffer) {
              var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            }
            console.log(arrayBuffer);

          }
      };
      xhr.open("POST","/pdf",true);
      xhr.responseType = 'arrayBuffer';
      xhr.send(blob);

    };
```

BACKEND:

```
app.post('/pdf',function(req,res){

  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
  console.log("Connected to Database");

  var bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: 'pdfs' });
  var CHUNKS_COLL = 'pdfs.chunks';
  var FILES_COLL = 'pdfs.files';
  // insert file
  var uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream('test.pdf');
  var id = uploadStream.id;

  uploadStream.once('finish', function() {

     console.log("upload finished!")

     var downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(id);
     downloadStream.pipe(res);
  });

  // This pipes the POST data to the file
  req.pipe(uploadStream);
});
});
```

Comment: If you want to download the pdf, then you need to set the following.


Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!!

Basically preset the response type to "arraybuffer" before you make the request using
`req.responseType = "arraybuffer"`

Now, once you receive the response, don't use `responseText`, instead use `response`. `response` contains the arraybuffer with the data for the file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that either the response is being outputted as plain binary which is not base64 encoded (still a buffer) or it is a compressed (gzip) response that needs to be uncompressed first.

Hard to pinpoint the issue without seeing the code though.

UPDATE:

Looks like you're missing the proper response headers.

Try setting these headers before the `downloadStream.pipe(res)`:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Comment: I posted some more info in my original question above.

Comment: Kerami I edited my original post with the code I'm using.

Comment: I get the same output when I console.log the response the text. I guess setting the headers doesn't help.

Comment: @ribarcheto94 I'm not sure what you're expecting the output to be, but you're uploading a pdf file and then trying to download it as a stream. The output you're getting is the binary data of the PDF file. It doesn't make much sense to console.log that as it will just show you gibberish. What you CAN do is download the file by settings the proper headers.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it really put me in the right direction. Now I have another problem I didn't really think about before and that is getting the file name on the server. Since I just pipe the data from the request to the upload stream, I don't have access to the data I'm sending. I also don't have a way of sending over a file name with my POST since I just send the blob. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Your stream is likely already a buffer.  You might be able to call `responseText.toString('utf8')` to convert the streamed data into readable string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion above but that didn't decipher the text. Check the output in my second answer above. If you have another idea please let me know. Thanks